# Como hacer ejecutar un script a elección según se seleccione una opción de una lista en javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy buscando la manera de poder mandar a llamar algunos scripts en javascript en un canvas según se de click en una de estas opciones. Los scripts los tengo en una carpeta aparte y quiero que cuando elija una opción solo corra ese script dentro de este canvas.
Como se darán cuenta por el HTML no estoy usando un formulario por lo que al buscar info sobre este método no logro encontrar algo parecido. Todos los scripts son de dibujos y acciones simples que corren dentro de este canvas.

```
<div class="select-box">
  <div class="options-container">
    <div class="option">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" id="automobiles" name="category" />
      <label for="automobiles">Bar chart drawing</label>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" id="automobiles" name="category" />
      <label for="automobiles">Choice of colored paints</label>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" id="automobiles" name="category" />
      <label for="automobiles">Circle animation</label>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" id="automobiles" name="category" />
      <label for="automobiles">Circle animation with bounce</label>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" id="automobiles" name="category" />
      <label for="automobiles">Creeper drawing</label>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" id="automobiles" name="category" />
      <label for="automobiles">Current time plus coordinales</label>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" id="automobiles" name="category" />
      <label for="automobiles">Drawing circles</label>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" id="automobiles" name="category" />
      <label for="automobiles">Square drawing</label>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="selected">
    Select a project
  </div>
</div>

<div class="canvas">    
  <canvas height="460" width="900"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola @Cris223511.dev, todos los scripts que tengo van dentro de un canvas, es por eso que busco que cada uno de estos se ejecute a elección. Son scripts sencillos de dibujos y acciones dentro de este canvas.

Comment: La pregunta fue cerrada por duplicado. ¿Ya revisaste la pregunta duplicada y sus respuestas? Si crees que no es un duplicado, explica por qué.

Comment: Hola @Mateo me parece que la pregunta no es duplicada porque en las respuestas de a otra pregunta no responden mi duda ya que la variedad está en poder ejecutar un script seguido de otro a medida que se seleccionen opciones a elegir y todo esto dentro de un canvas.